# concate string is truncated in mysql server

Tags: mysql, concatenation

When I am going to use Concat() string with more than 255 chars in my sql it is truncating the result.

I want to create a script at run time for creating tables but for more char 255 chars it is truncating.

Below is one example code i have given which is truncating result after 256 character:

```
SET @string1:='123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';
Set @string2:='adfuwehidfsdogfsdgjjdpofgjksdfjgjlsdfjgjklfdgldjslgfjlkjsdlfgreyreotyioiotryiuioreutyoureotyuoreu';
Set @string3:='^$$^%&%*&&)(*)**((_(__)(_(_()(&6745737563476938957234957423052304608304680803586080435683';

SET @finalresult:='123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890adfuwehidfsdogfsdgjjdpofgjksdfjgjlsdfjgjklfdgldjslgfjlkjsdlfgreyreotyioiotryiuioreutyoureotyuoreu^$$^%&%*&&)(*)**((_(__)(_(_()(&674573756347693895723495742305230460...';
SET @result:= (SELECT concat(@string1,@string2,@string3) );
Select length(@string1) AS S1,length(@string2) AS S2,length(@string3) AS S3,length(@result) AS R,length(@finalresult) F,@result;
```

If you run above set of query and see the output, value of length(@finalresult) will come 276 but value of length(@result) is coming 256 only. Means result is getting truncated after 256 character.

How can i concat any string which is of length more then 256 and it will not show truncated result?

Comment: Your question contains insufficient information to help you. Also, you want to create tables dynamically - provide the code so we can help. This way we can just guess (this is the reason you got the downvote).

Comment: Maximum length for the table name and column is 64 characters.

Comment: Yes, column name length and table name length is less then 64.

Comment: Please include the error it throws as well.

Comment: changed my code example and problem.

Comment: When I copy paste what you sent, the length for `@result` is 276. When I select it, I get 276 bytes also. Your `@finalresult` is 257 chars, which is what I get as well.

Comment: Yes it is. But how will i get value of result and final result equal. I want to concat some string and result of that i want full string not the truncated one.

Comment: Got it. I was using MYSQL Workbench which was truncating. Now after using TOAD for mysql this issue got solved.

Comment: Great, in the end there was no problem :)